# ReactJs: Child key prop without index

Tags: reactjs

Hello I tried to use the index as key in my components, but I ended up getting error from eslint and in the own doc of reactjs they recommend using the index in last option
Researching I found about generating a uuid for each component, but this seems to be costly

this is my array that I go foreach:

```
export const Tags: ITag[] = [
  {
    Title: 'DashBoard',
    Name: 'Default',
    Link: '../dashboards',
    Icon: AiOutlineDashboard,
    DropdownItems: null,
  },
  {
    Name: 'Analytic',
    Link: '../dashboards',
    Icon: AiOutlineLineChart,
    DropdownItems: null,
  },
  {
    Name: 'Inventory',
    Link: '../dashboards',
    Icon: BiStoreAlt,
    DropdownItems: null,
  },
  {
    Title: 'Pages',
    Name: 'Employees',
    Link: '../dashboards',
    Icon: TiGroupOutline,
    DropdownItems: [
      {Name: 'Employee List', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'View Employee', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'New Employee', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Any', Link: '/duoBoost'},
    ],
  },
  {
    Name: 'Departaments',
    Link: '../dashboards',
    Icon: FaRegBuilding,
    DropdownItems: [
      {Name: 'Elo Boost', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Duo Boost', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'MD10', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Coaching', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'Vitóriais', Link: '/duoBoost'},
    ],
  },
  {
    Name: 'Products',
    Link: '../dashboards',
    Icon: BsLightning,
    DropdownItems: [
      {Name: 'Elo Boost', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Duo Boost', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'MD10', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Coaching', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'Vitóriais', Link: '/duoBoost'},
    ],
  },
  {
    Name: 'Suppliers',
    Link: '../dashboards',
    Icon: BsBookmarkPlus,
    DropdownItems: [
      {Name: 'Elo Boost', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Duo Boost', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'MD10', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Coaching', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'Vitóriais', Link: '/duoBoost'},
    ],
  },
  {
    Name: 'Contracts',
    Link: '../dashboards',
    Icon: BsFileEarmarkText,
    DropdownItems: [
      {Name: 'Elo Boost', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Duo Boost', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'MD10', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Coaching', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'Vitóriais', Link: '/duoBoost'},
    ],
  },
  {
    Name: 'User List',
    Link: '../dashboards',
    Icon: RiGroupLine,
    DropdownItems: [
      {Name: 'Elo Boost', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Duo Boost', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'MD10', Link: '/eloBost'},
      {Name: 'Coaching', Link: '/duoBoost'},
      {Name: 'Vitóriais', Link: '/duoBoost'},
    ],
  },
];
```

And on my jsx I scroll through the list and do the following:

```
{tags.map((item) => (
        <>
          {item.Title ? (
            <TitleItem key={generateKey(item.Title.toString())} open={open}>
              {item.Title}
            </TitleItem>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
          <TagList
            open={open}
            key={generateKey(item.Name.toString())}
            sideBarStatus={open}
            tag={item}
            clickHandler={clickHandler}
          />
        </>
      ))}
```

and in my taglist I have to go through an array that is inside my array:

```
  {isOpen === true ? (
    <OpenedStyled active={active}>
      {dropItems.map((item) => (
        <li className="li-open" key={generateKey(item.Name.toString())}>
          <a href="#/">{item.Name}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </OpenedStyled>
  ) : (
    <ClosedStyled>
      {dropItems.map((item) => (
        <li className="li-closed" key={generateKey(item.Name.toString())}>
          <FaGhost size={18} />
          <a href="#/">{item.Name}</a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ClosedStyled>
  )}
```

my generateKeys:

```
export const generateKey = (pre: any) => {
  return `${pre}_${new Date().getTime()}`;
};
```

ss:

[image]

codesandbox with console warnings :
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bash-dn4l8?file=/src/App.tsx:5209-5772

Comment: In your taglist you do  item.toString() - which leds to [object Object] string. You should do item.Name.toString() for example

Comment: with that help remains with this warning, could you help me with this?
Check the render method of `MenuTags`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

Comment: you shouldn't be using a timestamp in your key. this will cause unnecessary re-renders. If you really want it to be off of a stringified version of your object you could just stringify it `JSON.stringify(item)`. Any value that is generated for a key that is going to change (like a timestamp or a uuid) is going to be inefficient and isn't generally considered a good practice. The key should be related to the data / content its rendering. This helps your re-renders stay tightly coupled with the actual data

Comment: @JohnRuddell can u look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bash-dn4l8?file=/src/App.tsx i try with json stringify but i already have this error: Check the render method of MenuTags. See reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your use of the wrapper fragment. That is the thing it is complaining about not having a key. You'll see if you replace your wrapping fragment with a DIV that has a key, that warning goes away. Here is your example with that change: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-chatterjee-t2ic1

Comment: Hah, that is because I forgot to save the file. Try again, it is actually changed now.

Comment: It is annoying to have to inject an element when you don't want to. However, you can keep a fragment and apply a key to it `<React.Fragment key={...}>` :)

Answer (score 1):

In `React` you should use `key` to render lists so that `React` can map states between renders and do the minimum number of renders.
If `key` is not specified, then the `index` of the element will be used. But you may be faced with a warning.

To fix this, you need to use `id`, but one that will not change between renders.
Your `generateKeys` method adds the current date, which is not true. Thus, on the contrary, you degrade the performance of `React`.

In your case, you can use the `Name` field as a unique key.
But remember, it's better to use `id`, because if you have two elements with the same `Name` field, you will get an error.

And you don't need to give multiple `keys` inside the `map`.
`key` is only needed by the `root` element. Therefore, your code for rendering inside the `map` should look something like this:

```
<MenuList open={open}>
    {tags.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.Name}>
            {item.Title ? <TitleItem open={open}>{item.Title}</TitleItem> : ""}
            <TagList
                open={open}
                sideBarStatus={open}
                tag={item}
                clickHandler={clickHandler}
            />
        </div>
    ))}
</MenuList>
```

And I made some fixes to the `Drop` component which also misused `key`.

The corrected code can be seen [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-kapitsa-9rq1b?file=/src/App.tsx)

P.S. And I would recommend reading in more detail about how to work with keys in the [official documentation React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Answer (score 0):

Generating a `uuid` could be worse than using an index.  In most cases, using the `index` value is just fine.  Having a fixed `id` to use as your `key` value is ideal because it eliminates the needs for re-renders when you move re-arrange items and add/remove from a list, but it is really just an optimization that *most programs don't even need*.

That being said, if you have an `id`, particularly for data coming from an external server-based source, use that.  If this is a static list, just add an `id` property to your objects.

Comment: yeah i try with json.stringify(item.name) but got : Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `MenuTags`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

Comment: can u helpme with this : https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-bash-dn4l8?file=/src/App.tsx?